# How do you use multiple quotes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath

What do you do when you already have single and double quotes in a URL, but then you need to wrap that URL in quotes?

For example:

```
<script src="http://(some url text)xpath='//*[@id="node-1075"]/div/div[1]/div/div/p[2]'"></script>
```

The node ID is wrapped in quotes, if I put the [URL](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url=%27http://www.lethbridgecollege.ca/program/administrative-office-professional%27%20and%20xpath=%27//*[@id=%22node-1075%22]/div/div[1]/div/div/p[2]%27) alone in the address bar it works, but as soon as it gets wrapped in quotes it doesn't, I can't escape the quotes either or else it will fail, what do I do?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to replace the double quotes with: %22
And the single quotes with: %27

So your URL would be:

```
"http://(some url text)xpath=%27//*[@id=%22node-1075%22]/div/div[1]/div/div/p[2]%27"
```

Here is the complete list of ASCII Encoding http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape them; usually you write (inside HTML files) double quotes first, then single quotes (the opposite in `.js` files, but that's my personal style); whenever you need the same in between you need to escape it.

**Example:**

```
document.getElementById("some").innerHTML = "<img src='something' onmouseover='change(\"ex1\")' />";
```

Notice that using the JavaScript escape character (`\`) isn't enough in an HTML context; you need to replace the double-quote with the proper XML entity representation, `&quot;`.

**Example:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="doIt('The &quot;Thing&quot;');">Do It!</a>
```

In your case, **I would recommend to [URL encode](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)** "the URL" though.